# Is it possible not to turn off an SSD in suspend/sleep/S3?

Tags: power-management, ssd, suspend

I'd like to keep the SSD (or HDD, it doesn't really matter though) powered on, even if I suspend (S3) the computer and prevent it from turning off during the sleep time. Is it somehow possible to achieve at all?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: Prevent sedutil encrypted SSD from locking.

Comment: It's probably not possible to control this with software; you could test whether it works at all using an external power supply (unless its a laptop where you can't hook such things up). Even so it might not work as the SSD might notice the host is gone. There is probably a completely different solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, this is not possible. Device states are controlled through firmware. If your system goes into S3, then your HDD/SS is put into D3 (device state 3) as well. There may be some exceptions depending on your BIOS configuration. There *may* be an option to prevent the firmware from putting a (S)ATA device in D3 when the system enters S3, but this is not likely.

One possible workaround would be to put your SSD on another system in a local network map the drive, or replace it completely with [NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage). This would isolate your system's sleep states from the drive, allowing it to stay awake.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably you're right, when entering S3, it's the ACPI firmware and not the kernel, who decides what to do with particular computer components.